# jquery ajax call to controller is posting null string

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I am posting id of a vehicle to controller from jquery ajax post.Ajax call is calling controller method but that string is always null.I searched a lot on web but any solution is not working.id has value in view but null in controller.please help me.

here is my code:
View

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
           function DeleteVehicle(id) {
          alert("working");
          if (confirm("Do you want to delete vehicle: " + id)) {
      //  var requestData = { 'vehicleId': vid }
        var dataPost={'id':id}
        $.ajax({



            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteVehicle", "Vehicle")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataPost,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success, sent data to controller");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error: " + data.responseText);
                }

        });
    }
}

$(function () {//when the document is ready
    $("#Delete").click(DeleteVehicle);
});
```

controller

```
        public ActionResult DeleteVehicle(string id)
        {

            //code
               return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

Comment: In Delete click function don't pass vehicle Id

Comment: if i dont pass vehicle id in delete function of contoller how can i get it in?? i have to use it for query purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you put httppost attribute on action method as below?

```
[httpPost]
 public ActionResult DeleteVehicle(string id)
        {

            //code
               return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

and in jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Delete").on("click",  function(){
       var id = $(this).).attr("id"); ////fetch id wherever you are fetching
       alert("working");
              if (confirm("Do you want to delete vehicle: " + id)) {
          //  var requestData = { 'vehicleId': vid }
            var dataPost={'id':id}
            $.ajax({



                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteVehicle", "Vehicle")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataPost,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success, sent data to controller");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                        alert("Error: " + data.responseText);
                    }

            });
        }


    });
```

for more information have a look at this

[MVC Deleting record using Javascript pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005071/mvc-deleting-record-using-javascript-pop-up)

Comment: from where you are getting id? coz in your code ur not passing id to the function "DeleteVehicle" @Wasfa

Comment: the id i posted through jquery ajax call,i am using this in controller parameter

Comment: I dont understand where how to fetch id.coz i was getting the id of selected row in web grid.please help me to clear my concepts

Comment: in my above code I have updated like you can get your id like $(this).id? make a try as above @Wasfa

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005071/mvc-deleting-record-using-javascript-pop-up @Wasfa

Answer (score 1):

`var dataPost` should be string, something like `var dataPost  = '{"id":"' + id + '"}'` and additional settings for `$.ajax` are as follows-->

> ```
> contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
> dataType: "json",
> ```

Comment: i tried this one but again id string is null in controller

Answer (score 0):

try to put `[HttpPost]` Attribute in your Action and try again.

Comment: in you Ajax call add `contentType: "application/json"` aftr `datapost`

Comment: i added this but id is still null

Comment: look `$(function () {//when the document is ready
    $("#Delete").click(DeleteVehicle);
});` You don't retreive the id here. you have to pass an `id` to the       method. Maybe `$(function () {//when the document is ready
          $("#Delete").click(DeleteVehicle($('#idText').val());
         });`

Comment: i am getting the id of selected vehicle on button click which is in web grid like this 
               <input type="submit" value="Delete"   onclick='DeleteVehicle("+ @item.VehicleId +")' id="#Delete_@item.VehicleId"/></text>) how can i pass this id param to DeleteVehicle method..

Comment: then try this one in your script before your delete method  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Delete").on("click",  DeleteVehicule(id));})

Comment: id is still null in controller :(

Comment: try @Neel solution just up